# If Statement to remove 0 Value Count in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am pulling data from a Warehouse database and displaying on a webpage.

This pulls all data.

```
@foreach (WarehouseCategoryModel categoryModel in Model.Categories)
{
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.ActionLink(categoryModel.Name, "Category", "-WarehouseCatalog", new { ide = categoryModel.ID }, null)</td>
         <td>@categoryModel.Count</td>
     </tr>
 }
```

I need to display each category where the Count is greater than 0.

I tried:

```
if(@categoryModel.Count > 0)
{
  <td>@categoryModel.Count</td>
}
```

Comment: You still need the cell even if the conditional is not executed, so put the <td> </td> outside the IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the `@` in the wrong place.  It should come before the `if`, like this

```
@if(categoryModel.Count > 0)
{
    <td>@categoryModel.Count</td>
}
else
{
    <td></td>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could explicitly filter out the items that you are iterating through using a [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) clause :

```
<!-- Only iterate through those with Counts greater than 0 -->
@foreach (WarehouseCategoryModel categoryModel in Model.Categories.Where(c => c.Count > 0))
{
     <!-- Do work here -->
}
```

If you wanted to handle scenarios where your Model or Categories were possibly null, you could add the following explicit check :

```
<!-- Ensure you have categories to loop through (avoids null exceptions) -->
@if(Model?.Categories != null)
{
      <!-- Only iterate through those with Counts greater than 0 -->
      foreach (WarehouseCategoryModel categoryModel in Model.Categories.Where(c => c.Count > 0))
      {
           <!-- Do work here -->
      }
}
else 
{
    <tr>
        <td>No Categories Available</td>
    </tr>
}
```

If you were planning on handling this, you would likely want to include this logic within your ViewModel itself as opposed to in the View, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: I like the Linq, but if he has no categories it won't execute the inner foreach of the loop.

Comment: That's correct. You could amend it to explicitly check if `Model` or `Model.Categories` is null and then consider serving something else like a "No Categories Available" message to the user. It really just depends on ones personal preferences.

Comment: Yeah, I like that solution.  You have one of the better answers for this question I believe.  Sadly the error is caused by a typographical error I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments. This should work:

```
<td>
if(@categoryModel.Count > 0)
{
   @categoryModel.Count
}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove @ from IF statement. You have already used in foreach loop.

```
if(categoryModel.Count > 0)
{
    <td>@categoryModel.Count</td>
}
else
{
    <td></td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of different approaches, the approach your taking please keep in mind will be slow with complex iterations.  I'll point out the potential code errors:

1. `@if` will trigger proper Razor, unless you have no `Html` inbetween your `foreach` and the `if`.

Sample:

```
// Valid
@foreach(var .... model.Categories)
{
     if(...)
     {

     }
}

// Invalid:
@foreach(var .... model.Categories)
{
     <td>Content</td>
     if(...)
     {

     }
}
```

2. Your model should be fully qualified, `Example.Models.Warehouse`.

You should show how you're actually declaring your `@model` for the View.  Which could help us distinguish further, also are you sure that you have more than one?  I would structure like this to hold the table row data better:

```
@if(Model != null)
{
    foreach(Example.Models.Warehouse model in Model.Categories)
    {
       <tr>
           <td>@model.Something</td>
       </tr>
    }
}
```

There isn't a need for a conditional, the loop won't execute if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thanks for all the feedback.  Here is my final solution.

```
            @if(categoryModel.Count > 0)
            {
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(categoryModel.Name, "Category","~WarehouseCatalog", new { id = categoryModel.Id }, null)</td>
                <td>@categoryModel.Count</td>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. I first checked if there are items in the list and if there are create the `HTML table`, loop through the items and create a `table row` for each item:

```
@if (Model.Categories.Count > 0)
{
     <table>
          foreach (WarehouseCategoryModel categoryModel in Model.Categories)
          {
               <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(categoryModel.Name, "Category", "-WarehouseCatalog", new { ide = categoryModel.ID }, null)</td>
                    @if(categoryModel.Count > 0)
                    {
                         <td>@categoryModel.Count</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    }
               </tr>
          }
     </table>
}
```

I hope this helps.